# Game theory multiple cooperative adversaries

Tags: reference-request, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Are there any papers talking about games with multiple cooperative adversaries?
I do research in computer science, and I am interested in this type of game. I am really not that knowledgeable in game theory, and googling isn't helping.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many papers by Milinde Tambe's group at USC, just go to his website and you'll find a lot of papers on attacker-defender strategies. They also deal with multiple attackers on a resource you wish to defend, though most of the work is on single attacker - single defender.